# Clearing MongoDb keys on IIS website

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb

New to IIS and Mongo, and I'm trying to find a way to clear the keys from my server to avoid an "item with the same key has already been added" exception.

```
IMongoDatabase _db;
IMongoCollection<BoardStorageItem> _boardsCollection;
public MongoDb()
    {
        var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost");
        _db = client.GetDatabase("KanbanDemonstration");

        BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<CardStorageItem>();
        BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<ColumnStorageItem>();
        BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<BoardStorageItem>();
        BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<EmployeeStorageItem>();


        _boardsCollection = _db.GetCollection<BoardStorageItem>("Board");
    }

    public BoardStorageItem GetBoardByName(string name)
    {
        var board = _boardsCollection.AsQueryable().FirstOrDefault(b => b.Name == name);
        return board;
    }

public class MongoConverter
{
    MongoDb _mongoDb;

    public MongoConverter()
    {
        _mongoDb = new MongoDb();
    }

    public BoardStorageItem GetBoardByName(string name)
    {
        return _mongoDb.GetBoardByName(name);
    }
}
```

and then for the code on the web page itself

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _mongoConverter = new MongoConverter();
    var board = _mongoConverter.GetBoardByName(TextBox1.Text);

    BoardName = board.Name;
    BoardId = board.Id;

    Label3.Text = BoardName;
    Label4.Text = BoardId;

    Session.Clear();
}
```

This works perfectly this first time I use the button to get a board, but if I try a second time, I get an exception "item with the same key has already been added" when attempting to new up MongoConverter. I had thought that clearing the session after would clear out the keys as well, but the only thing that seems to work is resetting the server itself.

Comment: What is `_boardsCollection`? What is the type and the purpose of it? You need to show that in your question so you have a [MCVE]. And what does your question have to do with IIS? Just because you're running in IIS doesn't mean the issue is IIS related, just like it's not Windows related or Intel related.

Comment: _db and _boardsCollection are both fields in MongoDb. I've edited them in.

Comment: Which specific line throws the exception?

Comment: Instantiating the new MongoDb in the MongoConverter constructor. System.ArgumentException: 'An item with the same key has already been added.'

Comment: That's not the root of where the exception is thrown. Your MongoDb contstructor contains no arguments, therefore it won't throw an ArgumentException (plus the obvious fact that you don't show any code that would throw an ArgumentException). Look again at your stack trace. Identify the first line of your code that throws the exception.

Comment: Stacktrace leads me to the first BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap in the MongoDb constructor.

Comment: Did you read [the documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.5/reference/bson/mapping/) for that method? That's the first thing you should do when you see an error coming from it. It quite clearly states: "The best place to register them is at app startup prior to initializing a connection with MongoDB.". Since the constructor gets called more than once, that's not the correct place to do that. Since this is ASP.NET, the likely place to put those is in the Application_Start event of your global application class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<T>()` should only be done once per type. And it should be done at application startup, before opening any database connections according to [the documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.5/reference/bson/mapping/).

Since you're in ASP.NET, put this in your Application_Start event in your global application class (global.asax)

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<CardStorageItem>();
    BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<ColumnStorageItem>();
    BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<BoardStorageItem>();
    BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<EmployeeStorageItem>();
}
```

You can make another method that calls it so you don't pollute your global application class if you want. And of course, remove the registrations from your constructor.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.